# How to set up git for wordpress theme development

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, themes

I am setting up 10 new local wordpress sites. I have 10 folders all named like this:

"name-of-site.com"

Inside each is a simple file structure:

- briefing files
- html
- wordpress

I want to set up a repository on git hub for the wp-content file but I can't find a way to create an alias. Surely the end result will be 10 different repos all called "wp-content"

How can I set up a separate repo for each wp-content folder and name it "name-of-site.com"

Is this glaringly obvious and I am being really stupid???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have the top level folted, that is "name_of_site.com" be the repository, and in that folder, you can create a `.gitignore` file to ignore the other directories you don't want, that is, the html and briefing files (if I understand your layout correctly). That way, you're simply tracking the Wordpress content. You can even move it up a level so that only the briefing files and the HTML are in separate directories and the WP content is in the "name_of_site.com" directory.

**Edit:**

After your comments, I think you could do it this way:

- Create  repos for each site you have and put the wp-content of those sites in the .gitignore file
- Create one repo for wp-content, which contains all your themes. Organize them according to your needs.
- Write a simple shell script that pulls the latest theme into your site's folder from the repo in the previous step. That way, every time you update your theme, you can go to your chosen site and just synch up with the latest pushed version.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah that is pretty much how I have it but I wanted to just have the folder "wp-content" as the repo so I only synch the theme and plugins folders as there's no point synching the whole wordpress installation. git won't allow an alias though as far as I can tell which means I need a bunch of repos called wp-content.

For now I'm just passing the whole wordpress installation to my repos which just seems a bit daft. I added the standard wordpress options to my .gitignore file but it still grabs the whole wordpress install when I synch the repo.

Comment: As I suspected...
Basically I just want to make a repo out of the wp-content folder as that is the folder that contains my themes and plug ins.

If I try and do this using the GUI I get an error as I cannot have 2 repos with the same name.

How do you set up git hub for developing multiple themes??